# WCF InstanceContextMode.PerSession

Tags: c#, wcf

if I use this: InstanceContextMode.PerSession, then for every client I initialize my service one time. Am I right?

**If I call a method that have [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)], JobImplement constructor gets called. Why?**

My Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class JobImplement : IJob
    {
        public static int Sum = 0;
        public JobImplement()
        {
            Sum++;
        }
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public void UselessMethod1()
        {
        }
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public void AddEmployee(string Name, string Age)
        {
        }
        public int GetSum()
        {
            return Sum;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Im using WSHttpBinding binding and here is my only client code.

My client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.IJob Service1 = new ServiceReference1.JobClient();
            Service1.UselessMethod1();//sum become [1]
            Service1.AddEmployee("","");//sum become [2]
            Console.WriteLine(Service1.GetSum());//show [2].
            Console.WriteLine(Service1.GetSum());//show [2].
            Console.WriteLine(Service1.GetSum());//show [2].
        }
```

Comment: It means that when people provide a suitable answer to your questions, you are expected to accept the best answer (by clicking on the hollow green checkmark beside it). Since it looks like my suggestion worked, let me rewrite it as an answer and you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service as written here uses the default value of the `ServiceBehavior.ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete` attribute, which is `true`.

This means that the methods enforcing transaction scope via `TransactionScopeRequired` will cause the service instance to be released and the next time a method is invoked, a new instance gets created despite your desired `InstanceContextMode`.

Changing the relevant attribute to `false` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your new instance of the service created every time client calls your service.  It might be because client terminated session (and your constructor).  For instance client closed proxy, in this case next time client calls service, new session will be created.  Did you check you are not closing proxy every time you connect to the service?

Comment: Im sory I didnt understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  I just rewrite what my description.  Hope this is better now :)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your edit. Second, I said that the session terminated -ONLY- when I call a method that includes this: TransactionScopeRequired = true. Btw, what is proxy? Im sory for my englush and have a great day!